# Vscode gdb debug don't run step by step

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, msys2

I try to set up HelloWorld project with vscode and gdb for cpp.

I use msys2.

It all sets just fine, the project compiles and runs, but I have problem with debugging it.

Here my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
]
```

I set `"stopAtEntry":false` but when I debugging, gdb don't run step by step. The terminal only show that build finished successfully.
I try to set `true` instead of `false`, then make a breakpoint. But nothing happen, it still same.

Comment: Do you compile your code with `-g`?

Comment: Yes, `args` in my `task.json` file is `-g {file} -o {file.exe}`

Comment: you write "but when I debugging, gdb don't run step by step. The terminal only show that build finished successfully."
So, does it run at all? Can you run the program at all?

Comment: " in my task.json file is -g {file} -o {file.exe}"
This seems to be wrong.
Given your file is named helloworld.cpp, it will result in a helloworld.cpp.exe, while in the launch config gdb expects an helloworld.exe.

I'm not even sure if it will create the .exe in the proper directory.

You should use 
`
"-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
`

Thus, with your tasks.json your compiled program will not be started by the debugger at al.